# Same source code yields different results in VS Code vs. Overleaf

Tags: overleaf, vscode

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting different results concerning the thickness of the text while running the same source code from VS Code and Overleaf. I'm using the `MikTex` distribution for VS Code.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % T1 encoding
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % german language
\usepackage{geometry} % format page layout
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} % headers
\usepackage{lastpage} % page numbering
\usepackage{hyperref} % links
\usepackage{doi} % doi
\usepackage{graphicx} % graphics
\usepackage{float} % float for graphics/tables
\usepackage{caption} % caption format
\usepackage{amsmath} % math commands
\usepackage{amssymb} % math symbols
\usepackage{lipsum}

% formate page
\geometry{left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, top=2.25cm}

% header
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ihead{Test}
\chead{Test}
\ohead{\today}

% foot
% \cfoot{\thepage\ / \pageref{LastPage}}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

% font
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont} % header font
\setkomafont{pagefoot}{\normalfont} % foot font
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries} % heading font

% captions
\captionsetup{format=plain, labelfont=bf}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Tabelle}
    \begin{tabular}{c c c}
        \hline\hline
        Col1 & Col2 & Col3\\
        \hline
        1 & 2 & 3\\
        4 & 5 & 6\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:tab1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

VS Code Version
[image: VS Code Version]

Overleaf Version
[image: Overleaf Version]

Comment: Overleaf uses TeXLive which uses `cm-super` as the default font. MikTeX does not. I'd recommend installing `cm-super` in MikTeX.